# Windows server - run nginx on port 80

Tags: windows-server-2003, nginx, port

Is there any way to get nginx running on port 80 on a windows 2003 server?  It seems that the http.sys service is running on port 80 which is the new "preferred way" for a web server to run on windows however nginx and apache don't yet use this.  Is there an easy way to stop this?

When I try and bind to port80 i get the following:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access
>    a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)

netstat shows

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

and that pid is

```
C:\nginx-1.2.5>tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 4"

Image Name                     PID Services
========================= ======== ============================================
System                           4 N/A
```

Comment: For me it was Skype (!) as suggested in this [other question.][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/478150/nginx-bind-to-0-0-0-080-failed-on-windows

Comment: Windows Web Server (IIS) may also cause this issue so try running: 'net stop WAS' to stop the service. Sometimes you may also need to run: 'net start W3SVC'. Note: Run cmd as admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was not http.sys and was in fact Sql Server Reporting Services... Disabled them and it was good to go.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my laptop. How did you figure out that SYSTEM(pid 4) was in fact "sql server reporting services" ?

Comment: I didn't. I just stopped the Reporting service and it's OK :)