# nginx: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx

I've been using nginx without any problem on windows for the last few months.
Today when I tried to start it up, I got this error:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: An attempt was made
>   to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)

Why did this start happening all of a sudden? I didn't change any configs or anything.

Comment: Is this on a real server or is it on a workstation?

Comment: windows workstation

Comment: In truth this is then probably a better for for [su].

Comment: Windows Web Server (IIS) may also cause this issue so try running: 'net stop WAS' to stop the service. Sometimes you may also need to run: 'net start W3SVC'. Note: Run cmd as admin.

Answer (score 51):

Check Skype.

Skype automatically updated itself, and turned the "use port 80" option back on.

It's in settions->advanced.

Comment: Unbelievable, but thanks. Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection

Comment: Sneaky M$. Very sneaky.

Comment: I just installed skype for web (beta). It installed a separate plugin for video, which I assume has the same behaviour. If you have a skype for web tab open in your browser, you may need to close that.

Comment: This answer only looks at Skype but there are a lot more programms that can cause this issue because of using port 80/tcp. For the easiest way see Jevgenis answer https://serverfault.com/a/478267/141615

Answer (score 12):

Check which ports are being used on your system.

There are some programs which bind port 80. For example TeamViewer, Skype, etc.

For an easy test type `http://localhost` in your browser and check which service appears.

Or ou can use a programm like CurrPorts by [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html).

Comment: In my case, it was IIS blocking port 80 - this appears to be a common problem. If `netstat -o` shows PID 4 listening on port 80, that's IIS.

Answer (score 8):

You can try run in CMD:

```
netstat -a | find "LISTENING"
```

also there was a piece of software called [TCPView](https://www.google.ee/search?q=portviewer&aq=f&oq=portviewer&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.4633&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=ru&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=tcpview&oq=tcpview&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.2164.4995.0.5162.18.10.5.3.3.0.68.462.10.10.0...0.0...1c.1.2.serp.8M1TgxsAY_g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42261806,d.bGE&fp=c16f9ff626018ae4&biw=1680&bih=925), which is very cool, and shows all runing process/occupied ports.

Comment: I used `netstat -ao` to also display the PID of the process blocking port 80 - then enabled the PID column in Task Manager to find out which process was blocking port 80.